# Win Form activated but buttons inside the form cannot be clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a material form with 3 buttons (back, stock, bom), when i click bom button it will display bom form that has a grid inside. double clicking on a row in the grid will load the material form (previously loaded) but containing the information of the clicked row (material->bom->material) my problem is on the second load of the material form the 3 buttons are not clickable(nothing happens clicking on these buttons) but the displayed info is already correct. So my question is how do i activate the buttons ?  (buttons are of type Resco.Controls.OutlookControls.ImageButton)

Comment: Are you closing the bom form or reopening the material form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet, with the information you provided, is that you call `ShowDialog()` on the grid form, which disables the material form. You can then only reactivate the material form by closing the grid form.

You could create a new instance of the material form, and display the new information on that, so when you close both that and the grid form, the original material form will be activated with its original content.

Be careful though, an application that allows users to "spam forms" like that can get very complex, both for you and the end user.

Comment: wow thanks for the reply. i'll check on the ShowDialog() function. thanks again will post feedback after

Comment: yes, i used ShowDialog(), can i use the Show() function instead?

Comment: @romz sure, that's also an option, just try and see how it feels.